# How to load relationship with Eloquent?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, lumen, eloquent-relationship

I have a Link model and each link has an owner (represented by ownerId in DB, which is a foreign key of the User table).

Here is the Link model :

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Link extends Model {

protected $table = "Link";

// ...

// Relationships
public function owner()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'ownerId', 'id');
}
```

}

When I use `$data = Link::find($linkId)->toJson();` in my LinkController, owner is included but is null in the JSON data. I also tried `$data = Link::with('owner')->find($linkId)->toJson();` and `$data = Link::find($linkId)->load('owner')->toJson();`

And when I use `$data = Link::find($linkId)->owner->toJson();`, I get the user data. Is there something missing in my code?

Is there a way to load the owner in the link object and to get it via JSON without additional requests / steps ?

Comment: Did you try with `append`? https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-serialization#appending-values-to-json

Comment: Yes I tried, but it doesn't work. The weird thing is that I can get the owner with `Link::find($linkId)->owner` but not with other methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the issue. The primary key in my User table was not standard (it was a string key instead of int).
I added the following lines in my User model :

```
public $incrementing = false;
public $keyType = 'string';
```

And now `$data = Link::with('owner')->find($linkId);` is just working fine.